# Advanced Custom Filed for User profile image cannot update second time : Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Adnaced Custom Fileds plugin in my Wordpress site. I have created and image type field for user profile image. I can able to update the profile image from front end and it's updating the profile image. I can view this in the admin Dashboard.

```
global $current_user;
$current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
...
update_field( 'profile_image', $attachment_id, "user_".$current_user_id );
```

Now the problem is I cannot display that uploaded image and also If I upload the file again then the field won't get updated.

```
$profile_image = get_field('profile_image', 'user_' . $current_user_id);
<img src="<?php echo $profile_image;?>">
```

The admin dashboard shows only the first uploaded image.

Please somebody help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved after digging into the ACF code:
I saved the profile image using the following statement:

```
update_metadata('user', $user_ID, "profile_image", $attachment_id);
```

And display it using below statement:

```
pimage = get_metadata("user", $userdata->ID, "profile_image");
$pimageurl = wp_get_attachment_url($pimage[0]);

<img src="<?php echo $pimageurl; ?>" id="profile-image">
```